# Issue in implementing rating bar in a fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, ratingbar

I'm trying to implement a rating bar into a fragment class that i have. But i always get a null point exception and crashes my app. The tutorials i read all shows how to implement a rating bar into a Activity class. How can i implement this in a fragment class?

My class

```
package com.f%%%%%%%%;

import java.util.ArrayList;
...................

public class TheaterDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    private ViewPager viewtheater;
    private ViewPageAdapter adaptertheater;
    private Activity activity;
    private CommonVariable commonVariable;
    private ProgressDialog dialog;
    private ArrayList<BaseElement> TheaterDetail;
    private ArrayList<BaseElement> theateritems;
    private int id;
    private String pos;
    private RatingBar ratingBar;
    private TextView txtRatingValue; 

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theaterdetail_fragment,
                container, false);

        addListenerOnRatingBar();

        activity = this.getActivity();

        pos= getArguments().getString(BundleKey.THEATERPOSITION.getKey());

        commonVariable = (CommonVariable) activity.getApplication();

        viewtheater = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.theaterdetail);

        dialog = new ProgressDialog(TheaterDetailFragment.this.getActivity());
        dialog.setMessage("Loading Theater Details");
        dialog.setCancelable(true);

        new BackGround().execute();

        return view;
    }

     public void addListenerOnRatingBar() {

            ratingBar = (RatingBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
            txtRatingValue = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtRatingValue);

            //if rating value is changed,
            //display the current rating value in the result (textview) automatically
            ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
                public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                    boolean fromUser) {

                    txtRatingValue.setText(String.valueOf(rating));

                }
            });
          }

    public class BackGround extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //Theater theaterdetail = (Theater) commonVariable.getTheater().get(id);

            TheaterDetail = JSONServices.getTheaterDetails(pos);

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        // check again
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {


            commonVariable.setTheaterDetail(TheaterDetail);

            adaptertheater = new ViewPageAdapter(commonVariable.getTheaterDetail(),
                    Element.THEATER_DETAIL.getType(), activity);

            viewtheater.setAdapter(adaptertheater);


            dialog.dismiss();



            super.onPostExecute(result);

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            dialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();

        }

    }

}
```

My layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/filmhall"
    android:background="@color/grey" >

    <!--
      <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    -->


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="15dp" />


   <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar1"
        style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
        android:isIndicator="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:numStars="10"
        android:rating="2.0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

     <TextView

            android:id="@+id/txtRatingValue"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:text="Rating :"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

*Additional fields were deleted!

The tutorial i refered

http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-rating-bar-example/

1.There was a error at findviewbyid at first and i fixed it by using getview().

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE!!

LOGCAT

```
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.fortuna.cinemalk.TheaterDetailFragment.addListenerOnRatingBar(TheaterDetailFragment.java:119)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.fortuna.cinemalk.TheaterDetailFragment.onCreateView(TheaterDetailFragment.java:98)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
12-30 12:01:23.456: E/AndroidRuntime(13134):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

LOGCAT for MD's and REDDY's answers

```
12-30 12:17:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(13545): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-30 12:17:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(13545): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-30 12:17:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(13545):    at com.fortuna.cinemalk.TheaterDetailFragment.addListenerOnRatingBar(TheaterDetailFragment.java:126)
12-30 12:17:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(13545):    at com.fortuna.cinemalk.TheaterDetailFragment.onCreateView(TheaterDetailFragment.java:100)
12-30 12:17:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(13545):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1460)
12-30 12:17:26.023: E/AndroidRuntime(13545):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:911)
```

Comment: where is your logcat???

Comment: I cant see any `Ratingbar` you implementing in your code...

Comment: You never used the ratingBar you declared. Therefore, it does not work.

Comment: please check now.i had deleted it before because it did not work.now i've updated it

Comment: @CraZyDroiD Try as per my answer.....

Comment: @CraZyDroiD what is at `line 126` ?

Comment: it's the last part of OnRatingChanged method

 boolean fromUser) {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this way pass `RootView` as argument to your `addListenerOnRatingBar(....)`

```
  @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.theaterdetail_fragment,
            container, false);

    addListenerOnRatingBar(view);
    ........
  }
```

and implement `addListenerOnRatingBar(....)` like so.

```
 public void addListenerOnRatingBar(View v) {

        ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
        txtRatingValue = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtRatingValue);

        //if rating value is changed,
        //display the current rating value in the result (textview) automatically
        ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
            public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
                boolean fromUser) {

                txtRatingValue.setText(String.valueOf(rating));

            }
        });
      }
```

Comment: i get null point exceptions at 

 ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {

and

addListenerOnRatingBar(view);

Answer (score 0):

Update this code

```
 ratingBar = (RatingBar) getView().findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
 txtRatingValue = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txtRatingValue);
```

Like this and keep this in `onCreateView()` Or pass that view to that method to use.

```
public void addListenerOnRatingBar(View view) {
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) view.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    txtRatingValue = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRatingValue);
}
```

and Call method from onCreateView() like this `addListenerOnRatingBar(view);`

Comment: i get null poin exceptions at

addListenerOnRatingBar();

and

ratingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating,
     boolean fromUser) {

Comment: this is the same way as M.D's answer.i did not work.

Comment: That is the answer for your problem..any one can answer like that only .. you have to use that code to resolve your issues. If it did't solve .. post the code and logs regarding the error.